# How to show work-related projects on personal GitHub account

Tags: work-experience

Our organization (small team in local government) does not have any official requirements to code or program anything, I just create scripts to make system administration easier.

We do not use any versioning tools, let alone GitHub (I'm not sure if many people around me heard of GitHub)

I'd like to showcase my coding, etc on personal GitHub account (you never know what future holds)

How to approach management using GitHub

- should I create GitHub with name of our team, and send link so it can be used in future
- if I create this GitHub account, can I replicate the projects from the work-related GitHub into my personal GitHub account (after all, I'm the one creating all these scripts)

How to bring up this topic to management? Are there any other points I should consider?

UPDATE

One issue is they may be touchy about why am I thinking about LinkedIn, and showcasing scripts I have worked on. Even though we move around from job to job, I am concerned that asking this question may subconsciously create a misunderstanding .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  would advise against publishing your work product. Other than the obvious issue that it's not yours to publish,  it's also a system security risk to show the world exactly how you're administering those systems. As an employer, I would be more concerned about your lack of care in protecting company IP than I would be impressed by your coding ability.

That said, if you could take some if the cool stuff you've done and repurpose it into a general utility without mentioning this is what you did at work,  it might be OK. It really depends on the terms of your employment and the content that you publish.

Comment: @ColeenV 'repurpose it into a general utility' now that makes lot of sense. I can certainly do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any other points I should consider?

You will need to double and triple check to ensure you are able to display government owned IP publicly.

Most places have all manner of policy regarding IP protection and posting it on the Internet as a whole may blatantly violate this.

---

What I would do is if you are intending to put larger amounts of information on your GitHub is to:

1. Find a relevant use for your skills outside your employer
2. Use that to write similar but different scripts

You may be able to get your employer to approve this, however make sure they understand that GitHub is publicly viewable information.

Comment: That's a good point. I will ensure code is scrubbed of such information.

Comment: @Sonihal that's not my point, my point is if you develop things on company property/etc it's generally _owned_ by the company. You can't just freely post it online most of the time.

Comment: Then of course, I have to ask Management about their policy for copying it to private GitHub account. I just wanted to know if there is anything else I should mention or bring up to management. I'm new to GitHub myself.